# What time will its temperature reach $30^◦C$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature

> Assume that the rate at which a body cools is proportional to the difference in temperature between the body and its surroundings. A body is heated to $110◦C$ and is placed in air at $10◦C$. After one hour, its temperature is $60◦C.$ At what time will its temperature reach $30◦C$?

My attempt :By the formula  $$T(t)-T(s)=(T(0)-T(s))e^{-kt}$$

$\color{orange}{\text{Given condition}}$: It takes $t=60\ minutes $ for temperature fall $\color{red}{110^\circ \ C \to 10^\circ \ C}$

Setting the corresponding values, final temperature $T(t)=10^\circ\ C$ , initial temperature $T(0)=110^\circ\ C$ & surrounding body temperature $T(s)=60^\circ\ C$  we get    $$10-60=(110-60)e^{-k(60)}$$

$$e^{-60k}=-1$$
$$-60k=\log(-1)$$
$$k=\frac{1}{-60}\log(-1)\tag 1$$

Now, for temperature fall $\color{red}{110^\circ \ C \to 30^\circ \ C}$ , setting $T(t)=30^\circ \ C$, $T(0)=110^\circ\ C$ & $T(s)=10^\circ\ C$ we get 
$$30-10=(110-10)e^{-kt}$$
$$e^{-kt}=\frac{20}{100}=\frac{1}{5}$$
$$\implies -kt=\ln\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)$$
Setting the value of $k$ from (1), we get time $t$ as follows
$$t\frac{1}{-60}\log(-1)=\log \frac{1}{5}$$

that is $$t=\log \frac{1}{5} \frac{-60}{\log(-1)}$$

Is my answer is correct or not ?

Comment: No.  Your "given condition" is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you used your variables in the question gave the impression that you aren't familiar with them, so I would try to help you out in that regime. (Otherwise this question in it's current form is Off-topic)

The question can be easily dealt with a proper understanding of [Newton's law of cooling](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_cooling). One of the assumptions there is that the rate of heat flow is proportional to the temperature gradient between the object and the surrounding i.e.,

$$\frac {dQ}{dt} = -k(T - T_{s})$$

Here $T$ is the temperature of the body and $T_s$ is the temperature of the surrounding. The equation in it's final form looks like the following :

$$\ln \left (\frac {T_i-T_s}{T_f-Ts} \right ) = \alpha t$$

Here $\alpha$ is constant due to the assumption that molar specific heat capacity of the substance is independent of the temperature i.e., is constant. $T_i$ is the initial temperature and $T_f$ is the final temperature. As of your question, $T_i = 110°\text C$, $T_f = 30°\text C$ and $T_s = 10°\text C$.

One important thing to note here is that when $T_f = T_s$ then the time it requires for the body to cool down approaches infinity which deviates from the reality that an object reaches to equilibrium with the surrounding in a finite time.